# Doing bulk load on database and monitoring the growth

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, bulk-insert

I have a small doubt on how this works. We came to know last night one of our sql databases had bulk load operation done with vendor giving that data of approx 300 GB would be bulk loaded.

Before and after when i checked the space used within database using gui as well as sp spaceused i can hardly see any decrease in unused space as free space has merely went down below 10 Gb.

Also I thought may be ldf, if not mdf and ndf growths but did not find anything there. Please help me understand how this works

database is in full recovery model

Comment: Sounds like not  that much data was loaded, or it was loaded and then deleted, or perhaps you're looking at the wrong database....

Comment: @TonyHinkle: looking at the correct database. just wandering if it was loaded and then deleted or updated should not that be bumping up the ldf's?

Comment: The simple way to verify/check is to restore a database using the backup file before the restore, and then compare the table sizes (like row #) btw the current db and the restored db. If you believe there is no much change, then either the vendor's bulk load is not loaded correctly or the load volume is not 300GB (well, of course, you need to consider table level compression as well in your judgement logic)

Comment: A bulk load would not make the log (.ldf) files grow very much.

Comment: Bulk load *is* fully logged in full recovery model, so it should log significantly to the log. Unless the database is "effectively" in simple mode (for instance switching to simple and back to full or the first full backup never produced).

Comment: @TiborKaraszi: Thanks for that info. But still ldf would be part of the entire db size, why i still dont see unused space decreasing as expected during the bulk load or is it the log backup running every 15 mins which truncated the log/

Comment: I never look at the database size as a whole. I always look at the log size separated from the data size. Sp_spaceused is too old-style and vague IMO (it has its roots in the old architecture). I use my sp_dbinfo, sp_tableinfo and sp_indexinfo when I look as space usage (on my web-site). I suggest you dig a bit deeper to see at a finer granulation what happens.